# Creating UEFI bootable live-usb using custom ISO

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, live-usb, custom-installer

I have a device with an AMD64 CPU but a UEFI bootloader that only supports i386.

I have made a custom Ubuntu 19.04 ISO installer using [Cubic](https://launchpad.net/~cubic-wizard) and have flashed it to a USB using usb-creator-gtk (Startup Disk Creator).

This creates two partitions on the USB:

[image: USB Partitions]

The first partition  formatted as ISO9660 and holds the ISO contents, the second is a FAT32 partition that contains only the .EFI boot files.

The second partition is what the tablet will boot from. Its contents come from an efi.img file stored inside /boot/grub on the ISO. This originally contained only AMD64 EFI files.:

[image: AMD64 boot files]

I have created my own replacement img.efi file and input a bootia32.efi file using these commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=efi.img bs=1M count=5
mkfs.fat efi.img
sudo mount -o loop,rw efi.img /media/efi
sudo cp -r <files> /media/efi
```

This successfully makes a bootable USB, *however* it doesn't load the installer Grub, it only loads a Grub command line.

I've used this `bootia32.efi` file to successfully load grub before, if I instead manually format the USB as FAT32, copy over the ISO files and put the custom EFI file inside of /EFI/BOOT then the device will boot into Grub as I would expect.

But I'd like to make an ISO that can be flashed as normal and boot fine.

My question is, what is the point of creating a separate partition to hold the boot EFI files as usb-creator-gtk does?
How do I make that partition load the installer's Grub config instead of just the Grub command  line?

Thank you

Comment: Some ISO (Windows) are larger than the FAT32 limit of 4GB. So you have to have separate FAT32 with UEFI boot files & then rest of system in another partition. It then looks like usb-creator-gtk is following that logic. If entire ISO extracted fits inside 4GB you can just do this & add the bootia32.efi file. UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: @oldfred thanks for clearing up why the partitions are separated, working around the 4GB restriction makes perfect sense. I realise I can manually make the bootable USB manually but I am deliberately trying to make an ISO that can be flashed using the built-in Startup Disk Creator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @oldfred for explaining that the seperated partitions is to overcome the 4GB file size limit for FAT32.

I've managed to create the bootable ISO by putting both the `boot` folder and the `EFI` folders from the ISO into the FAT32 (efi.img) partition.

I've modified the grub.cfg to launch from a different partition than the one it sits in.

This doesn't seem right to me because the original efi.img file only had three files:

```
BOOTx64.EFI
grubx64.efi
mmx64.efi
```

But, it works so I'm happy.

The exact structure of my efi.img file is this:

> ```
> .
> ├── boot
> │   └── grub
> │       ├── font.pf2
> │       ├── grub.cfg
> │       ├── loopback.cfg
> │       └── x86_64-efi
> │           ├── acpi.mod
> │           ├── adler32.mod
> │           ├── ahci.mod
> │           ├── all_video.mod
> │           ├── aout.mod
> │           ├── appleldr.mod
> │           ├── archelp.mod
> │           ├── ata.mod
> │           ├── at_keyboard.mod
> │           ├── backtrace.mod
> │           ├── bfs.mod
> │           ├── bitmap.mod
> │           ├── bitmap_scale.mod
> │           ├── blocklist.mod
> │           ├── boot.mod
> │           ├── bsd.mod
> │           ├── bswap_test.mod
> │           ├── btrfs.mod
> │           ├── bufio.mod
> │           ├── cat.mod
> │           ├── cbfs.mod
> │           ├── cbls.mod
> │           ├── cbmemc.mod
> │           ├── cbtable.mod
> │           ├── cbtime.mod
> │           ├── chain.mod
> │           ├── cmdline_cat_test.mod
> │           ├── cmp.mod
> │           ├── cmp_test.mod
> │           ├── command.lst
> │           ├── cpio_be.mod
> │           ├── cpio.mod
> │           ├── cpuid.mod
> │           ├── crc64.mod
> │           ├── cryptodisk.mod
> │           ├── crypto.lst
> │           ├── crypto.mod
> │           ├── cs5536.mod
> │           ├── ctz_test.mod
> │           ├── datehook.mod
> │           ├── date.mod
> │           ├── datetime.mod
> │           ├── diskfilter.mod
> │           ├── disk.mod
> │           ├── div.mod
> │           ├── div_test.mod
> │           ├── dm_nv.mod
> │           ├── echo.mod
> │           ├── efifwsetup.mod
> │           ├── efi_gop.mod
> │           ├── efinet.mod
> │           ├── efi_uga.mod
> │           ├── ehci.mod
> │           ├── elf.mod
> │           ├── eval.mod
> │           ├── exfat.mod
> │           ├── exfctest.mod
> │           ├── ext2.mod
> │           ├── fat.mod
> │           ├── file.mod
> │           ├── fixvideo.mod
> │           ├── font.mod
> │           ├── fs.lst
> │           ├── gcry_arcfour.mod
> │           ├── gcry_blowfish.mod
> │           ├── gcry_camellia.mod
> │           ├── gcry_cast5.mod
> │           ├── gcry_crc.mod
> │           ├── gcry_des.mod
> │           ├── gcry_dsa.mod
> │           ├── gcry_idea.mod
> │           ├── gcry_md4.mod
> │           ├── gcry_md5.mod
> │           ├── gcry_rfc2268.mod
> │           ├── gcry_rijndael.mod
> │           ├── gcry_rmd160.mod
> │           ├── gcry_rsa.mod
> │           ├── gcry_seed.mod
> │           ├── gcry_serpent.mod
> │           ├── gcry_sha1.mod
> │           ├── gcry_sha256.mod
> │           ├── gcry_sha512.mod
> │           ├── gcry_tiger.mod
> │           ├── gcry_twofish.mod
> │           ├── gcry_whirlpool.mod
> │           ├── geli.mod
> │           ├── gettext.mod
> │           ├── gfxmenu.mod
> │           ├── gfxterm_background.mod
> │           ├── gfxterm_menu.mod
> │           ├── gfxterm.mod
> │           ├── gptsync.mod
> │           ├── grub.cfg
> │           ├── gzio.mod
> │           ├── halt.mod
> │           ├── hashsum.mod
> │           ├── hdparm.mod
> │           ├── help.mod
> │           ├── hexdump.mod
> │           ├── hfs.mod
> │           ├── hfspluscomp.mod
> │           ├── hfsplus.mod
> │           ├── http.mod
> │           ├── iorw.mod
> │           ├── jfs.mod
> │           ├── jpeg.mod
> │           ├── keylayouts.mod
> │           ├── keystatus.mod
> │           ├── ldm.mod
> │           ├── legacycfg.mod
> │           ├── legacy_password_test.mod
> │           ├── linux16.mod
> │           ├── linuxefi.mod
> │           ├── linux.mod
> │           ├── loadbios.mod
> │           ├── loadenv.mod
> │           ├── loopback.mod
> │           ├── lsacpi.mod
> │           ├── lsefimmap.mod
> │           ├── lsefi.mod
> │           ├── lsefisystab.mod
> │           ├── lsmmap.mod
> │           ├── ls.mod
> │           ├── lspci.mod
> │           ├── lssal.mod
> │           ├── luks.mod
> │           ├── lvm.mod
> │           ├── lzopio.mod
> │           ├── macbless.mod
> │           ├── macho.mod
> │           ├── mdraid09_be.mod
> │           ├── mdraid09.mod
> │           ├── mdraid1x.mod
> │           ├── memrw.mod
> │           ├── minicmd.mod
> │           ├── minix2_be.mod
> │           ├── minix2.mod
> │           ├── minix3_be.mod
> │           ├── minix3.mod
> │           ├── minix_be.mod
> │           ├── mmap.mod
> │           ├── moddep.lst
> │           ├── morse.mod
> │           ├── mpi.mod
> │           ├── msdospart.mod
> │           ├── mul_test.mod
> │           ├── multiboot2.mod
> │           ├── multiboot.mod
> │           ├── nativedisk.mod
> │           ├── net.mod
> │           ├── newc.mod
> │           ├── ntfscomp.mod
> │           ├── ntfs.mod
> │           ├── odc.mod
> │           ├── offsetio.mod
> │           ├── ohci.mod
> │           ├── part_acorn.mod
> │           ├── part_amiga.mod
> │           ├── part_apple.mod
> │           ├── part_bsd.mod
> │           ├── part_dfly.mod
> │           ├── part_dvh.mod
> │           ├── part_gpt.mod
> │           ├── partmap.lst
> │           ├── part_msdos.mod
> │           ├── part_plan.mod
> │           ├── part_sun.mod
> │           ├── part_sunpc.mod
> │           ├── parttool.lst
> │           ├── parttool.mod
> │           ├── password.mod
> │           ├── password_pbkdf2.mod
> │           ├── pata.mod
> │           ├── pbkdf2.mod
> │           ├── pbkdf2_test.mod
> │           ├── pcidump.mod
> │           ├── play.mod
> │           ├── png.mod
> │           ├── priority_queue.mod
> │           ├── probe.mod
> │           ├── procfs.mod
> │           ├── progress.mod
> │           ├── raid5rec.mod
> │           ├── raid6rec.mod
> │           ├── random.mod
> │           ├── read.mod
> │           ├── reboot.mod
> │           ├── regexp.mod
> │           ├── reiserfs.mod
> │           ├── relocator.mod
> │           ├── romfs.mod
> │           ├── scsi.mod
> │           ├── serial.mod
> │           ├── setjmp.mod
> │           ├── setjmp_test.mod
> │           ├── setpci.mod
> │           ├── shift_test.mod
> │           ├── signature_test.mod
> │           ├── sleep.mod
> │           ├── sleep_test.mod
> │           ├── spkmodem.mod
> │           ├── squash4.mod
> │           ├── syslinuxcfg.mod
> │           ├── terminal.lst
> │           ├── terminal.mod
> │           ├── terminfo.mod
> │           ├── test_blockarg.mod
> │           ├── testload.mod
> │           ├── test.mod
> │           ├── testspeed.mod
> │           ├── tftp.mod
> │           ├── tga.mod
> │           ├── time.mod
> │           ├── trig.mod
> │           ├── tr.mod
> │           ├── true.mod
> │           ├── udf.mod
> │           ├── ufs1_be.mod
> │           ├── ufs1.mod
> │           ├── ufs2.mod
> │           ├── uhci.mod
> │           ├── usb_keyboard.mod
> │           ├── usb.mod
> │           ├── usbms.mod
> │           ├── usbserial_common.mod
> │           ├── usbserial_ftdi.mod
> │           ├── usbserial_pl2303.mod
> │           ├── usbserial_usbdebug.mod
> │           ├── usbtest.mod
> │           ├── verify.mod
> │           ├── video_bochs.mod
> │           ├── video_cirrus.mod
> │           ├── video_colors.mod
> │           ├── video_fb.mod
> │           ├── videoinfo.mod
> │           ├── video.lst
> │           ├── video.mod
> │           ├── videotest_checksum.mod
> │           ├── videotest.mod
> │           ├── xfs.mod
> │           ├── xnu.mod
> │           ├── xnu_uuid.mod
> │           ├── xnu_uuid_test.mod
> │           ├── xzio.mod
> │           └── zfscrypt.mod
> └── efi
>     └── boot
>         ├── bootia32.efi
>         ├── BOOTx64.EFI
>         ├── grubx64.efi
>         └── mmx64.efi
> ```

Some of those probably aren't necessary, but I'm not concerned about the extra 10MB of space it uses.

This is my grub.cfg inside the img.efi file, note the `set root=(hd0)`:

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

set timeout=5
menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server" {
    set root=(hd0)
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
menuentry "Run from internal disk" {
    linux    (hd1,gpt2)/boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd   (hd1,gpt2)/boot/initrd
}
```

If anyone can shed further light on what should be inside of the efi.img file, please let me know.